# Multiline java exception regex in rubular

Tags: regex, spring, logging, fluentd, rubular

I've these kind of logs in an application and I want to parse them. I've created a regex but it doesn't work as expected as it doesn't parse the full stack trace in the log. Here's my current expression:

```
^(?<time>[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+\s+[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+.[0-9]+)[\s]*(?<level>[^\s]+) (?<pid>[\d]+) --- \[(?<thread>.*)\] (?<class>[^\s]+)[\s]*:[\s]*(?<message>.*)
```

These the logs that I get from my application:

```
2018-06-26 09:01:42.144 DEBUG 1 --- [io-9090-exec-10] c.stakater.gateway.logging.MethodLogger  : Method called: StackService.fetchStack(..)
2018-06-26 09:01:42.149 ERROR 1 --- [io-9090-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Stack with ID: 166a998f-dbb2-44a3-be86-asd Not Found!] with root cause
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Stack with ID: 166a998f-dbb2-44a3-be86-asd Not Found!
    at com.stakater.gateway.repository.StackRepositoryService.findById(StackRepositoryService.java:29) ~[classes!/:1.0.16]
    at com.stakater.gateway.repository.StackRepositoryService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fe7f2cc7.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;) ~[classes!/:1.0.16]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at com.stakater.gateway.repository.StackRepositoryService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ddd17ba6.findById(&lt;generated&gt;) ~[classes!/:1.0.16]
    at com.stakater.gateway.service.StackService.fetchStack(StackService.java:118) ~[classes!/:1.0.16]
    at com.stakater.gateway.service.StackService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$97e6baa6.invoke(&lt;generated&gt;) ~[classes!/:1.0.16]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.12.RELEASE]
2018-06-26 09:01:42.144 DEBUG 1 --- [io-9090-exec-10] c.stakater.gateway.logging.MethodLogger  : Method called: StackService.fetchStack(..)
```

You can see [here](http://rubular.com/r/42JD7FMkiT) that the regex doesn't match the full stack trace. Any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that Rubular is tailored to test Onigmo/Oniguruma regexps, Java uses `java.util.regex` library.

Comment: I'm going to use this regex in fluentd which is based on ruby

Comment: To support Ruby like syntax, use [`(?m)^(?<time>\d+(?:-\d+){2}\s+\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s*(?<level>\S+) (?<pid>\d+) --- \[(?<thread>.*?)\] (?<class>\S+)\s*:\s*(?<message>.*?)(?=\g<time>|\Z)`](https://regex101.com/r/Pvbgq3/2). I am not sure what text should land in `thread` and `class` fields, please clarify.

Comment: Also, try `^(?<time>\d+(?:-\d+){2}\s+\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s*(?<level>\S+) (?<pid>\d+) --- \[(?<thread>[\s\S]*?)\] (?<class>\S+)\s*:\s*(?<message>[\s\S]*?)(?=\g<time>|\Z)`

Comment: Both work as expected. But i'm not sure how you did it with the last one. Can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?<time>\d+(?:-\d+){2}\s+\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s*(?<level>\S+) (?<pid>\d+) --- \[(?<thread>[\s\S]*?)\] (?<class>\S+)\s*:\s*(?<message>[\s\S]*?)(?=\g<time>|\Z)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Pvbgq3/2).

The main points are:

- `.` is replaced with `[\s\S]` (or, you may keep `.`, but use `(?m)` at the start of the pattern for `.` to match line break chars, it is a Ruby only behavior of `m` flag)
- `.*` is too greedy, use a lazy quantifier, `.*?`
- To only match up to the date, a lookahead is used, `(?=\g<time>|\Z)`. It checks if there is a time pattern (`\g<time>`, a subroutine that recurses the `time` group pattern) or end of string (`\Z`) right after the current location.

I also "prettified" `[^\s]` as `\S`, `[\d]` as `\d`, `[\s]` as `\s`, and grouped repetitive patterns. You may also replace spaces with `\s+` to make sure any amount of any whitespace chars are matched.